# Как упростить и оптимизировать код обработки событий, модальных окон и ajax запросов ?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Задача такая:
Есть 3 действия:  Создать, Редактировать и Удалить. Все работает следующим образом:

Когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку создать, открывается модальное окно с формой для ввода данных, когда он нажимает Создать, обращение идет к функции, которая делает ajax запрос, примерно так все работает и для редактирования и удаления.

**Как это выглядит:**

```
  //--------------------------------------------
    // СОБЫТИЯ [Добавить, Редактировать, Удалить]

    /**
     * Удалить точку
     */
    $(document).on("click",".confirm-delete", function() {
        var content = '';
        var x = $(this).data('coordx');
        var y = $(this).data('coordy');
        var coordId = $(this).data('coordid');
        content+= '<p>Вы действительно хотите удалить точку x'+x+' y'+y+'?</p>';
        content+= '<br/><br/><div class="text-center"><a href="#" class="button grey" onclick="deleteCoord('+coordId+'); return false">Подтверждаю</a></div>';
        content+= '<div class="load"><div class="loader"></div></div>';
        content+= '<div class="responce"></div>';
        content+= '<div class="error"></div>';
        modalText(content, 'confirm-delete');
    });

    /**
     * Добавить точку
     */
    $(document).on("click",".add", function() {
        viewAddEditCoordTpl();
    });

    /**
     * Редактирование точку
     */
    $(document).on("click",".edit", function() {
        viewAddEditCoordTpl($(this).data('coordid'), this);
    });

    /**
     * Содержимое модального окна [добавить и редактировать точку]
     */
    function viewAddEditCoordTpl(coordId, $this) {

        coordId = typeof coordId   !== 'undefined' ? coordId : false;
        $this   = typeof $this     !== 'undefined' ? $this   : false;

        var x = '';
        var y = '';
        var field_name = '';
        var button = '<a href="#" class="button green" onclick="addCoord(); return false">Добавить точку</a>';

        // Редактирование
        if(coordId) {
           x = $($this).data('coordx');
           y = $($this).data('coordy');
           field_name = ($($this).data('field_name'))?$($this).data('field_name'):'';
           button = '<a href="#" class="button green" onclick="editCoord('+coordId+'); return false">Редактировать точку</a>';
        }

        var content = '';
        content+= '<form action="/server/controller.php" method="post" id="formCoord">';
        content+= '<p><label>Координата X:</label> <input type="text" name="coordx" value="'+x+'" placeholder="Введите число" /></p>';
        content+= '<p><label>Координата Y:</label> <input type="text" name="coordy" value="'+y+'" placeholder="Введите число" /></p>';
        content+= '<p><label>Описание:</label> <input type="text" name="fieldName" value="'+field_name+'" placeholder="Описание координаты" maxlength="200" class="fieldName" /></p>';
        content+= '</form><br />';
        content+= '<div class="text-center">'+button+'</div>';
        content+= '<div class="load"><div class="loader"></div></div>';
        content+= '<div class="responce"></div>';
        content+= '<div class="error"></div>';

        modalText(content, 'test');
    }

    //--------------------------------------------
    // ДЕЙСТВИЯ [Добавить, Редактировать, Удалить]

    /**
     * Создание точки 
     */
    function addCoord() {

       $('.load').show();
       $('.responce').hide();
       $('.error').hide();

       var x = $('#formCoord input[name=coordx]').val();
       var y = $('#formCoord input[name=coordy]').val();
       var fieldName = $('#formCoord input[name=fieldName]').val();

        // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
        // and remember the jqXHR object for this request
        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  '/backend/controller.php',
            data: { 'action':'addCoord', 'x':x, 'y':y, 'fieldName':fieldName}
        }).success(function(responce) {

            var checkResponce = jQuery.parseJSON( responce );

            // Возникла ошибка
            if (typeof checkResponce.error !='undefined') {
                $('.error').html(checkResponce.error).show(300);
            }else {
                // Жадный рендер 
                renderAll(false,responce);
                // Закрыть все окна
                $.arcticmodal('close');
            }
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log( "error" );
        })
        .done(function() {
            $('.load').hide();
        })
    };

    /**
     * Редактирование точки 
     */
    function editCoord(coordId) {

        var x = $('#formCoord input[name=coordx]').val();
        var y = $('#formCoord input[name=coordy]').val();
        var fieldName = $('#formCoord input[name=fieldName]').val();

       $('.load').show();
       $('.responce').hide();
       $('.error').hide();

        // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
        // and remember the jqXHR object for this request
        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  '/backend/controller.php',
            data: {'action':'editCoord', 'coordId':coordId,  'x':x, 'y':y, 'fieldName':fieldName}
        }).success(function(responce) {

            var checkResponce = jQuery.parseJSON( responce );

            // Возникла ошибка
            if (typeof checkResponce.error !='undefined') {
                $('.error').html(checkResponce.error).show(300);
            }else {
                // Жадный рендер 
                renderAll(false,responce);
                // Закрыть все окна
                $.arcticmodal('close');
            }
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log( "error" );
        })
        .done(function() {
            $('.load').hide();
        })
    };

    /**
     * Удаление точки 
     */
    function deleteCoord(coordId) {

       $('.load').show();
       $('.responce').hide();
       $('.error').hide();

        // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
        // and remember the jqXHR object for this request
        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  '/backend/controller.php',
            data: { 'action':'deleteCoord', 'coordId':coordId}
        }).success(function(responce) {
            // жадный рендер 
            renderAll(false,responce);
            // Закрыть все окна
            $.arcticmodal('close');
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log( "error" );
        })
        .done(function() {
            $('.load').hide();
        })
    };
```

Извиняюсь за такое кол-во кода, но хотел показать сразу все.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это дело можно упростить, может как-то избавиться от дублирования ? 
Если  у кого есть идеи как записать это проще, пожалуйста поделитесь.

Comment: ModalText не может принять аргументом jquery объект ? onclick всё портит. 

у вас ajax запрос же одинаково обрабатывается, вынесите его в отдельную функцию.

Comment: ModalText в принципе может, но не понял зачем. По поводу ajax таки вариант, спасибо. 

А вот что значит "onclick всё портит", что с ним можно сделать?

Comment: можно сразу делать так:

     $(document).on('click','.coordEdit',editCoord); //раньше создания диалога, вместо document, что-нить поближе к тому где модал создается
    
    //.............
    button = $('<a href="#" class="coordEdit button green">Редактировать точку</a>').data('coordID',coordId);

в смысле очень не рекомендуется использовать onclick в разметке, при js,

Comment: ещё angular как раз для таких штук удобен. особенно в связке angular-bootstrap (пример на [angular-ui](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview));

Comment: пример пустой к сожалению

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/6Pbv3NGWo2lBpmgZu5wu?p=preview